# OpenAL Segmentation Fault Before Main

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, openal

I'm writing a game engine in C++ that utilizes SDL for graphics and OpenAL for audio. I'm developing on Windows XP compiling with MinGW and debugging with GDB. I discovered the problem when I ran the debugger and, before even reaching main(), the program received a Segmentation Fault. I was (and still am) confused why a segfault would occur before the program reached main. However, even though GDB said it received SIGSEGV, the program continued happily and ran exactly as I would expect it to (displayed graphics, played sounds, music, etc.)

Of course, being a game engine, there are a lot of different components, so I got rid of all components (excluded them from compiling or commented them out) and added them back in until I discovered that my calls to OpenAL were causing the segfault. Oddly enough though, the segfaults still occurred *before* main, and commenting out the OpenAL function calls subsequently caused the segfault to stop occurring on the next run.

So, to test out my hypothesis, I made a separate project with minimal code and linked only with OpenAL32, and voila! Segfault. This is literally the code in its entirety:

```
#include <al.h>

int main()
{
    alGetError();
    return 0;
}
```

I can replace alGetError() with any other OpenAL function call (even alcOpenDevice(), which is *designed* to be the first library call), and the segfault occurs. Remove alGetError(), and the segfault disappears.

The backtrace directly at the point of the segfault shows the following:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x7c918af2 in ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x7c918af2 in ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c901046 in ntdll!RtlEnumerateGenericTableLikeADirectory ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00e461a0 in ?? ()
#3  0x77dd6cd8 in RegCloseKey () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll
#4  0x77dde88d in RegCreateKeyExA () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll
#5  0x77de473f in RegCreateKeyA () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll
#6  0x6650127a in ?? () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbsys.dll
#7  0x7c90118a in ntdll!LdrSetAppCompatDllRedirectionCallback ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#8  0x66500000 in ?? ()
#9  0x7c91c342 in ntdll!LdrHotPatchRoutine ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#10 0x7c915c69 in ntdll!RtlValidateUnicodeString ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#11 0x7c915dcb in ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess ()
   from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#12 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

RtlpWaitForCriticalSection() makes it seem like a thread issue, which OpenAL runs in a separate thread if I'm not mistaken. However I'm not too familiar with multithreaded programming.

I compiled my project (the whole game engine, in its current state) under Linux and no segfault message occurs, and the program runs as I would expect it to (this means there are a couple other errors/segfaults that I still have to fix up but I have a handle on them :P).

I'm not sure exactly what my question is. I guess I'll leave it with this question: is the segfault signal I'm receiving a result of the way I'm implementing/linking OpenAL, or is it something beyond my control that the OpenAL library causes? I would assume it's not a problem with OpenAL itself, considering the broad user base of the library, but who knows. Maybe it's a problem with the fact that I am linking my C++ project to a C library?

**UPDATE** : I've been researching this for a few days now, and I'm getting very frustrated. The only results I can find for "Segfault before main" are: "You have a static constructor, which is called before main" and "Oh, it actually wasn't before main. I need to learn how to use a debugger."

Well, I've never heard of static constructors in C++. And anyway, I reproduced the error without any classes to begin with. And I only run into the segfault signal when I'm using the debugger, because the program runs perfectly if it just blasts through the signal (a.k.a continuing). Putting a breakpoint on the first instruction in main or even on main(), the segfault occurs before the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: have you tried calling alutInit(0, NULL); before alGetError() ? Maybe OpenAL must be initilized before calling any of its functions.

Comment: That's a good thought. I tried it, but to no avail. ALUT is "AL Utilities" so it's designed to be used in addition to OpenAL; I shouldn't need to initialize or use ALUT if I just want to use OpenAL. I wrote my own file loaders so I wouldn't want to mess with it anyway. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: I'll add that a call to alutInit(0, 0) on it's own causes the same problem (i.e. substituting the OpenAL library call with the ALUT call). Logical, since ALUT depends on OpenAL.